# Div being moved if it contains a form - IE

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer

I am not sure how to explain this one as it has baffled me and I don't have a great deal of code to show what I mean, BUT I will try:

I have an ASP.NET website using Master pages. The source would show something like:

```
<body>
    <form id="main" runat="server">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="main_content">
                <div id="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="right"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I allow the user to set the content of the "content" div using a WYSIWYG editor that accepts HTML. The problem I am seeing in IE8 (not sure about others)(Mozilla fine) is when I have a form in the content the source changes to this:

```
<body>
    <form id="main" runat="server">
        <div id="main">
             <div id="left"></div>
             <div id="main_content">                   
                <div id="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="right"></div> // BEEN MOVED?!?! 
</body>
```

which is then throwing the div below the main content instead of sitting beside it. I find this really odd and I know it has something to do with the form as I have tested without and the div shows in the right place.

EDIT: Is it something to do with wrapping form tags inside each other?

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, dear long day I think :)

You can't nest a form within a form so make sure the content from the editor doesn't contain a form.

Sigh ..